# POM Error while importing spring boot maven project into STS

Tags: maven-3

org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifest(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject, org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration)

This error showing in the first line of POM.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in pom.xml

```
<properties>        
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.6</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```